# Race conditions when fetching, updating, and deleting documents using Firebase with AngularFire

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I've come across an issue that I'm having difficulty solving. There are two issues both of which appear to be caused by race conditions.

1.) The drawPoll() function is getting executed before the this.poll.choices are done appending. I confirmed that this is the issue by manually adding a 3 second setTimeout(). How do I make sure the drawPoll() function only executes after the choices.ForEach() iteration is complete?

2.) When calling the vote(choiceId) function and decrementing a choice the firebaseService observable does not pick up the correct value for "votes" because the observable kicks in before the vote deletion has finished executing. How do I re-arrange my code so that the observable waits until the vote document deletion is complete?

I tried to wrap the choices.forEach iteration in a promise but had difficulty getting this to work. And I wasn't sure where to even start to do a promise chain for the decrementChoice() and getChoices() since the getChoices() function doesn't always rely on the decrementChoice or incrementChoice() function when it's initilaized. It only relies on those when a vote is casted. Attached is my component and firebase service. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**poll.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Chart from 'chart.js';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FirebaseService } from '../services/firebase.service';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { CardModule } from 'primeng/card';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-poll',
  templateUrl: './poll.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./poll.component.scss']
})
export class PollComponent implements OnInit {
  chart:any;
  poll:any;
  votes:[] = [];
  labels:string[] = [];
  title:string = "";
  isDrawn:boolean = false;
  inputChoices:any = [];
  username:string = "";
  points:number;

  @Input()
  pollKey: string;

  @Output()
  editEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  @Output()
  deleteEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firebaseService.getPoll(this.pollKey).subscribe(pollDoc => {
      // ToDo: draw poll choices on create without breaking vote listener
      console.log("details?", pollDoc);
      // Return if subscription was triggered due to poll deletion
      if (!pollDoc.payload.exists) {
        return;
      }
      const pollData:any = pollDoc.payload.data();
      this.poll = {
        id: pollDoc.payload.id,
        helperText: pollData.helperText,
        pollType: pollData.pollType,
        scoringType: pollData.scoringType,
        user: pollData.user
      };

      if (this.poll.pollType == 1) {
        this.title = "Who Do I Start?";
      }
      if (this.poll.pollType == 2) {
        this.title = "Who Do I Drop?";
      }
      if (this.poll.pollType == 3) {
        this.title = "Who Do I Pick Up?";
      }
      if (this.poll.pollType == 4) {
        this.title = "Who Wins This Trade?";
      }

      // Populate username and user points
      this.firebaseService.getUser(pollData.user).subscribe((user:any) => {
        const userDetails = user.payload._document.proto;
        if (userDetails) {
        this.username = userDetails.fields.username.stringValue;
        this.points = userDetails.fields.points.integerValue;
        }
      });

      this.firebaseService.getChoices(this.pollKey).pipe(first()).subscribe(choices => {
        console.log("get choices");
        this.poll.choices = [];
        choices.forEach(choice => {
          const choiceData:any = choice.payload.doc.data();
          const choiceKey:any = choice.payload.doc.id;
          this.firebaseService.getVotes(choiceKey).pipe(first()).subscribe((votes: any) => {
            this.poll.choices.push({
              id: choiceKey,
              text: choiceData.text,
              votes: votes.length
            });
          });
          this.firebaseService.getVotes(choiceKey).subscribe((votes: any) => {
            if (this.isDrawn) {
              const selectedChoice = this.poll.choices.find((choice) => {
                return choice.id == choiceKey
              });
              selectedChoice.votes = votes.length;
              this.drawPoll();
            }
          });
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.drawPoll();
        }, 3000)
      });
    });
  }

  drawPoll() {
    if (this.isDrawn) {
      this.chart.data.datasets[0].data = this.poll.choices.map(choice => choice.votes);
      this.chart.data.datasets[0].label = this.poll.choices.map(choice => choice.text);
      this.chart.update()
    }
    if (!this.isDrawn) {
      console.log("text?", this.poll.choices.map(choice => choice.text));
      this.inputChoices = this.poll.choices;
      var canvas =  <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById(this.pollKey);
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
          labels: this.poll.choices.map(choice => choice.text),
          datasets: [{
            label: this.title,
            data: this.poll.choices.map(choice => choice.votes),
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(255, 4, 40, 0.2)",
              "rgba(19, 32, 98, 0.2)",
              "rgba(255, 4, 40, 0.2)",
              "rgba(19, 32, 98, 0.2)",
              "rgba(255, 4, 40, 0.2)",
              "rgba(19, 32, 98, 0.2)"
            ],
            borderColor: [
              "rgb(255, 4, 40)",
              "rgb(19, 32, 98)",
              "rgb(255, 4, 40)",
              "rgb(19, 32, 98)",
              "rgb(255, 4, 40)",
              "rgb(19, 32, 98)",
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
          }]
        },
        options: {
          events: ["touchend", "click", "mouseout"],
          onClick: function(e) {
            console.log("clicked!", e);
          },
          tooltips: {
            enabled: true
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: this.title,
            fontSize: 14,
            fontColor: '#666'
          },
          legend: {
            display: false
          },
          maintainAspectRatio: true,
          responsive: true,
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                precision: 0
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      });
      this.isDrawn = true;
    }
  }

  vote(choiceId) {
    if (choiceId) {
      const choiceInput:any = document.getElementById(choiceId);
      const checked = choiceInput.checked;
      this.poll.choices.forEach(choice => {
        const choiceEl:any = document.getElementById(choice.id);
        if (choiceId !== choiceEl.id && checked) choiceEl.disabled = true;
        if (!checked) choiceEl.disabled = false;
      });
      if (checked) this.firebaseService.incrementChoice(choiceId);
      if (!checked) this.firebaseService.decrementChoice(choiceId);
    }
  }

  edit() {
    this.editEvent.emit(this.poll);
  }

  delete() {
    this.deleteEvent.emit(this.poll);
  }

}
```

**firebase.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { map, switchMap, first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseService {
  // Source: https://github.com/AngularTemplates/angular-firebase-crud/blob/master/src/app/services/firebase.service.ts
  constructor(public db: AngularFirestore, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  getPoll(pollKey) {
    return this.db.collection('polls').doc(pollKey).snapshotChanges();
  }

  getChoices(pollKey) {
    return this.db.collection('choices', ref => ref.where('poll', '==', pollKey)).snapshotChanges();
  }


  incrementChoice(choiceKey) {
    const userId = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
    const choiceDoc:any = this.db.collection('choices').doc(choiceKey);
    // Check if user voted already
    choiceDoc.ref.get().then(choice => {
      let pollKey = choice.data().poll
      this.db.collection('votes').snapshotChanges().pipe(first()).subscribe((votes:any) => {
        let filteredVote = votes.filter((vote) => {
          const searchedPollKey = vote.payload.doc._document.proto.fields.poll.stringValue;
          const searchedChoiceKey = vote.payload.doc._document.proto.fields.choice.stringValue;
          const searchedUserKey = vote.payload.doc._document.proto.fields.user.stringValue;
          return (searchedPollKey == pollKey && searchedChoiceKey == choiceKey && searchedUserKey == userId);
        });
        if (filteredVote.length) {
          // This person aleady voted
          return false;
        } else {
          let votes = choice.data().votes
          choiceDoc.update({
            votes: ++votes
          });
          const userDoc:any = this.db.collection('users').doc(userId);
          userDoc.ref.get().then(user => {
            let points = user.data().points
            userDoc.update({
              points: ++points
            });
          });
          this.createVote({
            choiceKey: choiceKey,
            pollKey: pollKey,
            userKey: userId
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

  decrementChoice(choiceKey) {
    const choiceDoc:any = this.db.collection('choices').doc(choiceKey);
    const userId = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
    choiceDoc.ref.get().then(choice => {
      let pollKey = choice.data().poll
      let votes = choice.data().votes
      choiceDoc.update({
        votes: --votes
      });
      const userDoc:any = this.db.collection('users').doc(userId);
      userDoc.ref.get().then(user => {
        let points = user.data().points
        userDoc.update({
          points: --points
        });
      });
      // Find & delete vote
      this.db.collection('votes').snapshotChanges().pipe(first()).subscribe((votes:any) => {
        let filteredVote = votes.filter((vote) => {
          const searchedPollKey = vote.payload.doc._document.proto.fields.poll.stringValue;
          const searchedChoiceKey = vote.payload.doc._document.proto.fields.choice.stringValue;
          const searchedUserKey = vote.payload.doc._document.proto.fields.user.stringValue;
          return (searchedPollKey == pollKey && searchedChoiceKey == choiceKey && searchedUserKey == userId);
        });
        this.deleteVote(filteredVote[0].payload.doc.id);
      });
    });
  }


  createVote(value) {
    this.db.collection('votes').add({
      choice: value.choiceKey,
      poll: value.pollKey,
      user: value.userKey
    }).then(vote => {
      console.log("Vote created successfully", vote);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("Error creating vote", err);  
    });
  }

  deleteVote(voteKey) {
    this.db.collection('votes').doc(voteKey).delete().then((vote) => {
      console.log("Vote deleted successfully");
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("Error deleting vote", err);
    });
  }

  getVotes(choiceKey) {
    return this.db.collection('votes', ref => ref.where('choice', '==', choiceKey)).snapshotChanges().pipe(first());
  }

}
```

** UPDATE **

I was able to solve issue #2 by creating a separate subcription just for vote updates. The code feels rather cumberson but at-least now #2 is no longer an issue. I'm still encountering the same issue though with #1 where the drawPoll() function is getting executed before this.poll.choices are done iterating and appending. I updated the question to reflect my updated code.

Comment: Just as a side thought: you have a lot of nested logic (IMO, not necessarily fact). Is it possible to utilize promises with async/await?

Comment: Yeah, that's good feedback. Thank you. I think my initial approach was to just get it working and then go back and simplify/refactor. Do you think incorporating async/await might help with the issue I'm currently facing?

Comment: Well, I personally found the nested logic a little harder to follow, so actually debugging for me was a little tough. I think some places can benefit from it. Your first problem can possibly be a good place to start since it is waiting on a subscription. For #2 I'm not fully sure, but I think async/await on this (instead of relying on the subscription) will do a similar magic for you. It won't update the value since you won't be subscribed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to be subscribed because the whole purpose of the app and the main reason why I chose firebase, to begin with, is that I need the dashboard to update in real-time

Comment: Oh, yeah I'm with ya there now. Sorry, I was misunderstanding Q2/the logic flow.

Would you be able to swap the forEach logic that is after the `if checked` and `if !checked` logic to above it?

Comment: Yep, I can do that.